# How to truncate every line after pattern

Tags: substitute

I just don't undstand the VIM help for pattern matching and substitution. I've tried.

I have many lines of code, like so:

```
G1 X139.164 Y115.348 E8.40357 ; perimeter
G1 X138.903 Y115.845 E8.57778 ; perimeter
G1 X136.919 Y119.355 E9.82896 ; perimeter
G1 X135.204 Y125.148     F250    
G1 X133.565 Y124.281 E11.75686     F250
```

I want to remove uppercase **E** *and everything following it on each line* - or truncate each line, beginning with the **E**.

Things I've tried:

```
:%s/E\>//g
:1,$/E\>\.//
:%s/E\>\zs.*//
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last attempt is almost correct.  I would use this:

`:%s/E.*//`

The OCD part of me would also want to remove any spaces before the `E`.  That could be done with:

`:%s/\s*E.*//`

The `\>` was causing your attempts to fail because by default numbers are considered part of the word.  See `:help \>` and `:help iskeyword` for more info.

The `\zs` isn't necessary in this case since you are trying to replace the entire search pattern.  If you were to use it, you would want it in front of the `E` since you want to remove the `E` as well.  The `\zs` would be useful if, for example, you only wanted to remove the `E` and everything after on lines starting with `G2`.  Then you could do something like:

`:%s/^G2.*\zs\s*E.*//`

Comment: Thanks very much. While all three answers worked, this one helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this command:

```
:1,%s/E.*$//g
```

Comment: You don't need the `//g` at the end. Also, you can just do `:%` instead of `:1,%`

Comment: You don't need the `$` either, since `*` matches as much as possible (though it doesn't hurt).

Comment: I am just used to going it that way,  Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 5):

[@Christopher Collins' solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12642/2920) is great. Here's one more way you could do it:

```
:%norm fED
```

This tell vim to press `fED` on each line as if you had typed it in normal mode. `fE` will move the cursor forward to the first `E`, and `D` deletes everything until the end of the line.

Comment: had no idea that you could do this!  This is a much better way of doing it.

Comment: @ChristopherCollins I won't say _better_. `:%s/E.*//` is neat, efficient, probably much faster, and it works with `sed`, and the venerable `vi` as well.