# How to truncate all lines at a certain length?

Tags: global-command

Much like [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12640/11454), I've failed to put this together successfully on my own.

I want to truncate lines in my file so that no line is over 100 characters in length.

I can go to position 100 on each line and execute a <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> (or just a <kbd>D</kbd>), but what command will do this for every line in the file? Note: some lines are less than 100 characters.

Comment: Do a macro if you know how to do it for a single line. Or smth like `:%normal 100|d$`

Comment: @MaximKim, `:%norm 100|D` will not work because `100|` will just move to the end of the line on lines shorter than 100 chars. Meaning it will delete the last character for those lines.

Comment: @PeterRincker this might work, with virtual edit set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Using a substitution

```
:%s/.\{100}\zs.*//
```

Find 100 characters, `.\{100}` then start the match, `\zs`, and select the rest of the line, `.*`. Replace the match with nothing.

For more help see:

```
:h :s
:h /\.
:h /\{
:h \zs
:h /\*
```

#### Using filter

```
:%!cut -c 1-100
```

Use filter, `:!`, with a range of the entire file, `%`. This will take the entire buffer and pass the text as stdin to `cut` and replace the buffer text with the stdout of our command. Use `-c 1-100` to get the first 100 characters.

For more help see:

```
:!
:range
```

#### Using `:normal`

```
:%norm! v99lyVp
```

For every line, `%`, run command, `{cmd}` via `:normal! {cmd}`. Select and yank the first 100 characters via `v99ly`. Then replace the entire line, `V` with the just yanked 100 characters, `p`.

In theory, it would be nice to use `101|D`, however `101|` will just move to the end of the line for too short of lines. This will result short lines losing their trailing character. `|` also jumps by screen columns so could be messed up by indention.

For more help see:

```
:h :norm
:h :range
:h v_p
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very, very much!